# Image augmentation в object detection модели машинного обучения

Tags: машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети

хочу расширить набор данных машин, состоящий из 1100 экземпляров, который будет использован при обучении нейронной сети с object detection алгоритмом. Вопроса возникло два, кто-нибудь может, пожалуйста, подсказать?

Вопросы:

1. Сколько нужно создать дополнительных augmentation экземпляров моих картинок? Я имею ввиду, что у меня 1100 экземпляров, нужно ли мне применять image augmentation к каждой картинке / к каждой второй-картинке / к каждой картинке и несколько раз ?
2. Как именно нужно проводить image augmentation для нейронной сети с алгоритмом object detection? Просто отодвинуть картинку машины в сторону не пойдет? Как понимаю можно отзеркалить, отдалить, повернуть, приблизить. А что можно еще попробовать?

Comment: https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html

Comment: @MaxU, полезная информация, спасибо!

Comment: По количеству - это пробовать нужно. Нейросети это пока ещё во многом искусство, а не чистая инженерия. Нужно пробовать разные варианты и смотреть, какие лучше, какие хуже. В идеале нужно, наверное, все картинки по-всякому трансформировать, если по времени модель это потянет.

Comment: @CrazyElf, спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При обучении нейросети аугментацию входных картинок я делаю всегда. Делаю это на лету (без сохранения на диск).
Примерный список преобразований:

- rotation (повороты)
- random crop
- blur
- motion blur
- sharpen
- gaussian noise
- salt & pepper
- в моем случае "изобрел" шум крупными зернами (размер несколько пикселей)
- автоконтраст
- сепия
- hue/saturation
- изменение яркости/контрастности
- фильтр шумоподавления (cv2.fastNlMeansDenoisingColored)
- фильтр пикселизации
- jpeg compression

Из этого списка случайным образом беру несколько фильтров и со случайными параметрами применяю к картинке. Нужно следить за тем, что бы картинка слишком сильно не портилась.

PS. Например для Питона есть готовые библиотеки https://github.com/mdbloice/Augmentor или https://imgaug.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/api_augmenters_arithmetic.html , в torchvision.transforms тоже есть фильтры для аугментации.